# How to solve $f'(x) = b f(x+1)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What are the solutions of the following differential equation, as a function of $b$?

$$
f'(x) = b f(x+1)
$$

It seems quite simple, however, [Mathematica cannot solve it](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16876/how-do-i-interpret-an-error-message-from-dsolve)...

I tried to guess a solution of the form $f(x)=\exp(a x)$. Then:
$$
f'(x) = a f(x)
\\
f(x+1) = e^a f(x)
$$
so we need to find an $a$ such that $a = b e^a$. This equation has solutions - either imaginary or real. For example, for $b=1$ there is an imaginary solution: 
$$a_{b=1} = 0.318132 - 1.33724 i$$
for $b=1/4$ there are two real solutions:
$$a_{b=1/4} \in \{0.357403,2.15329\}$$

Are these the only solutions?

Comment: Initial conditions for a delay equation must be a whole interval not one point. There will be solutions other than exponential depending on this initial data.

Comment: The equation you study is usually called a [delay differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation).

Comment: Your guess does not satisfy $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: @amsmath yes, I noticed this and removed the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) to solve $\;a=be^a\;$ as $\;a=-W(-b).\;$ For real values of $a$ and $b$ there are only two branches of the $W$ function so at most two solutions.

Comment: These are the solutions to $a = b e^a$, but are these the only solutions to the differential equation?

Comment: Consider $f(x)=f(x+1)$. What are all  the solutions?

Comment: Any function on $[0,1]$ determines a solution... there are infinitely many.

Comment: I think this is a similar situation.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi It is indeed a similar situation, any $C^1$ function $f : [0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ can be an initial condition in this problem. If you had the reverse delay $f'(x)=bf(x-1)$, then you could use the Laplace transform to solve the problem. But this problem is "noncausal" so that won't work.

Comment: @Ian It is "causal" in the opposite direction though.

Comment: @Somos Good point! In that regard you can think of it as a delay equation in backwards time. So you can just reverse time (which flips the sign on $b$, effectively) and then use Laplace transforms.

Comment: @Ian this seems interesting, can you elaborate?